# AVPlayer view in UIView is missing controls

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, avplayer

In AVPlayer default video forward slider and play button are not showing if  AVPlayer is added to UIView

```
NSURL *videourl= [NSURL URLWithString:strUrl];
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videourl];         

AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController new];            

playerViewController.player = player;

playerViewController.view.frame = ViewAV.bounds;

AVPlayerLayer* playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
playerLayer.frame = ViewAV.bounds;

playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
//externalPlaybackVideoGravity
playerLayer.contentsGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;

[ViewAV.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
[ViewAV addSubview:playerViewController.view];

[playerViewController.player play];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `showsPlaybackControls` and `requiresLinearPlayback` to true,

```
playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = YES;
playerViewController.requiresLinearPlayback = YES;
```

Currently, you didn't add `playerViewController` as child `viewController` so you will not be able to see anything. Add as below,

```
[self addChildViewController:playerViewController];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
[self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];
```

Comment: @ishanbhatt Can you try adding as childViewController as i updated in the answer?